# Load PartialView with Ajax in asp.net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I have a problem whilst using PartialViews and Ajax. I use a custim Helper to create an Imagelink with Ajax properties (found it on the internet).

The problem is when I click on the image it **renders the same page** in the targetDiv instead of the PartialView he's supposed to load

Here is my Code:

*The update function in the view*

```
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateTarget(data) {
            // the HTML output of the partial view
            var partialView = data.get_data();
            // the DOM element representing the targetDiv
            var targetDiv = data.get_UpdateTarget();
            // updates the target with the partialView
            $('"targetDiv').append(partialView)
            // return false to prevent the automatic update of the placeholder
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

*The TagetDiv and the Ajax custom helper*

```
<tr>
            <td><div id="create"></div></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <% if (10 < 20) {%>
            <tr>
                <td><%= Ajax.ImageActionLink("/Content/Images/add_link.png","Add a new link", "Create", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "updateTarget", UpdateTargetId = "create" })%></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
```

*The custom helper*

```
public static string ImageActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, string actionName, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions)
        {
            //Creates the image
            var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
            builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
            builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
            builder.MergeAttribute("height", "24");
            builder.MergeAttribute("width", "24");

            //Creates the link
            var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, ajaxOptions);
            return link.ToString().Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
```

*The Create function*

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return PartialView("Create");
        }
```

*Create.ascx (not in shared)*

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyLinks.ViewModels.LinkViewModel>" %>

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Link.Url) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Link.Url) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Link.Url) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.Link.Description) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Link.Description)%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Link.Description)%>
        </div>

        <a href="javascript:document.form_name.submit();"><img src="/Content/Images/confirm_link.png" alt="Accept this link"/></a>

<% } %>
```

**Please help me I've being searching for hours now for a good solution!**

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reference `MicrosoftAjax.js` as well:

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also when calling the helper you don't need both `OnSuccess` and `UpdateTargetId`. The following should be enough and specify an insertion mode:

```
<%= Ajax.ImageActionLink(
    Url.Content("~/Content/Images/add_link.png"),
    "Add a new link", 
    "Create", 
    new AjaxOptions { 
        UpdateTargetId = "create", 
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter 
    }
) %>
```

Now you can remove the `updateTarget` function as it's not necessary.

Comment: Updating works whitout the Onsuccess but I still don't get the PartialView Create.ascx, but instead I get the same page inserted in the targetDiv.

Comment: @Myst3ric, when you debug the AJAX with FireBug what does the server send as response? Does it send a partial HTML or the entire page?

Comment: FireBug says that data.get_UpdateTarget() not a funtion is. I use this in my function that updates the view